# Github not showing activity under my profile whenever I commit/push

Tags: git, github

I've been working on two different projects, and for both, whenever I commit & push, nothing shows up on my profile contribution.

I went to the commits to get the URLs, appended .patch to see if my email was linked to the commits, and I also checked if github had my email in the settings.

Both of these are true, so I'm so confused and baffled as to why nothing shows up.

Comment: Are the repositories actually hosted on GitHub?

Comment: Yes - https://github.com/DavidRodden/YV

Comment: Your commit does show up in this account: https://github.com/David-Rodden. Maybe you should delete/stop one account and stick to only one.

Answer (score 3):

For those who find this question through an internet search: Check that your email is correct! I spelled my own last name incorrectly when configuring it in terminal. Working perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

It will not be shown in activity log if the branch you have pushed is not the default one.

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#commits

Answer (score 1):

The contributions are linked to a GitHub account through the email used when you commit.
Your repo [YV](https://github.com/DavidRodden/YV) includes commits done with the email `davidrodden273@gmail.com`, which is the one from [David-Rodden](https://github.com/David-Rodden)

If both [DavidRodden](https://github.com/DavidRodden) and [David-Rodden](https://github.com/David-Rodden) have the same email, that would explain the lack of contribution, as GitHub does not know to which account it needs to attribute your last commits.
Make sure both accounts have different emails, or keep only one.

Comment: This might be stupid, but how do you get to see the email linked to these profiles?

Comment: @nullpointer I don't actually: I cloned the repo and did a git log. But it still might be visible through GitHub API.

Comment: I tried baffling with Inspect, but can't find the info in the response or request for any call.

Comment: @nullpointer thne I can only assume that both accounts are using the same email, which might explain the lack of contributions

Answer (score 0):

Your commits look like they are coming from the account `David-Rodden` instead of the intended `DavidRodden`.

Sign out and then sign back into the intended account.

For help doing this: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/

Comment: Am I not allowed to commit from the account David-Rodden, though?

Comment: Oh, do you want the contributions to show up on the `David-Rodden` account? If so, check out this post: https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/ 

These are the common reasons why your commits don't show up.

Comment: I read that previously, but everything I followed made no difference

Answer (score 0):

Probably an issue with an incorrect email or user name. [This](https://alvinalexander.com/git/git-show-change-username-email-address/) should help anyone wanting to check/change their Git credentials.

**TL;DR**

View the credentials

```
git config --list
```

Change credentials

```
git config --global user.name <your username>
git config --global user.email <your email>
```